# replace wrong html entities using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

unfortunately, I have to deal with faulty HTML entities in a text, for example

> &middot,

instead of the correct entity with the ending semicolon.

I tried

```
$pattern = "/^&[a-zA-Z]+?,/";
$replace =  "/^&[a-zA-Z]+?;/";
$detailtext = preg_replace($pattern,$replace, $detailtext);
```

but it doesn't work... This is driving me nuts, I'm new to regular expressions and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example for `$detailtext`:

```
$detailtext = "Unterputz-Einsätze<br>mit Federklemmen (Verbindungsklemmen nach VDE 0632). <br>Die Einsätze können wahlweise mit Standard- oder Flächenabdeckung <br>bestückt werden.<br>Wippschalter<br>10 AX 250 V&sim,<br>Ausführung: Universalschalter (Aus-Wechsel)<br>"
```

Comment: You have `#` in your pattern and `&middot,` does not contain the hash. So, it is not that surprising.

Comment: show the `$detailtext` value

Comment: tried it without the #. added it because of an answer i read on SO. Does not work without it either

Comment: Are they always at the beginning of the string? If not, remove `^`. See [`'~&[a-z]+[,;]~i`](https://regex101.com/r/nX4xI5/1).

Comment: they are not at the beginning of the string. removed the ^, but now i get &[a-zA-Z]+?; instead of the correct entity

Comment: I see now, you do not understand the concept of [*backreferences*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$pattern ="/(&[a-zA-Z]+),/"
$replace ="$1;";
$detailtext = preg_replace($pattern,$replace, $detailtext);
```

The parenthesis will capture entities that are followed by "," and you can retrieve them with "$n", n being the capture group number. So replace with "$1" followed with ending semicolon.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot for the short but very clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\&.*)(\,)/", "$1;", $str);
```